# 500 error on Coldfusion 8

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

when I add an anchor tag to a cfoutput I get a 500 error.  this is the code:

```
<div class="content">
 <div id="priceline">
  <div id="producttitle2">
   <a href="http://#path#/p/#urlref#">#MIRTHSearchProducts.mach_Description#</a>
  </div>
  <div id="productprice2">#DollarFormat(MIRTHSearchProducts.mach_ListPrice)#</div>
 </div>

 <div style="clear:both"></div>
 <div id="imageline">
  <a href="http://#path#/inc/_getProdImage.cfm?id=#mach_ItemNumber#_#ext#" rel="##overlay_prod" style="text-decoration:none; float:left; margin-right:12px;"><img src="http://#path#/images/product/60/#mach_ItemNumber#_1.jpg" width="60" border="0" /></a>

  <div style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin-right:6px;">
    #MIRTHSearchProducts.web_descr_short#
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you get an error loading the page with this code? Where is your path variable defined?

Comment: This is what I have has the path variable:<cfif MIRTHSearchProducts1.recordcount EQ 1>
            <cflocation url="http://#path#/p/#MIRTHSearchProducts1.urlref#" addtoken="no">
        </cfif>

Comment: Try wrapping it in a try catch and see if it gives any useful info

Comment: where do you say `<cfset path = 'something'>` ?

Comment: Looks like cflocation is going to unexisting location. Check the output of http://#path#/p/#MIRTHSearchProducts1.urlref#, and try navigating it directly in browser. Also the code you have posted, does not have cflocation code that you have pasted in the comments. The anchor tag itself can't throw 500 error unless you navigate to the page.

Comment: "Error Executing Database Query.[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\inetroot\mirth1\mirth1\individual-products.cfm, line: 126 "